# How to query data views in Child Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views, sfmc-business-unit

Can someone please help me on this?

I have a scenario where I need to query the child business unit data views from child business unit.

When I'm trying to query on  _open or _click  data views it throws me an error saying that 
(
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: _Open is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views.
)

Any Suggestions on how to query the data views?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to open a support case to get the dataviews turned on for this account

Answer (score -1):

System data views like `_Open`, `_Sent`, `_Clicked` are stored in the parent BU.
To query this you add e.g. `ENT._Open` to your query.
The system data view `_Job` is stored in child BU so you can query as usual here. Great article from Mateusz Dąbrowski on this.
https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views/